# I want to write a script in Python that store the list of images file names and print them into a text file

Tags: python, command-line

I created one folder 'JPG' and put list of images in that folder along with python code but when I tried to run this code, It prints out './imagename.jpg' but i want only 'imagename.jpg' in the text file.

```
import os
def GetFiles(dir,f):
    basedir = dir
    subdirs = []
    for fname in os.listdir(dir):
        fileName = os.path.join(basedir, fname)
        if os.path.isfile(fileName):
            if fileName.endswith(".jpg"):
                f.write(fileName+"\n")
                print fileName
        elif os.path.isdir(fileName):
            subdirs.append(fileName)
    for subdir in subdirs:
        GetFiles(subdir,f)
f=open("fileName.jpg",'w')
GetFiles('./',f)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print fileName.replace('./' '')#Repace parameter 1 with parameter 2
```

Comment: I changed it to print fileName.replace('./', '') but in the text file, it still print './imagename.jpg' but in terminal it is showing 'imagename.jpg' though. how to fix this problem? is it because for 'GetFiles('./',f)' ?

Comment: I assume you have changed the print to replace but not the actual write? If this is the case then f.write(fileName.replace('./','')+"\n")

Answer (score 0):

Before saving the name of the file in your text file or printing it, run this:

```
fileName= fileName.replace('/','')
```

Note that according to [PEP 8 on variables naming](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you should write 
`file_name` instead of `fileName`